# Leaflet Overlay with created PNG

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, png, overlay

I created a png picture and wanted it do display on a leaflet map.

I tried it like in the code below but it does not work.

> (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Any Ideas how i could do this? Here is the code.

```
    var pic = new PNGlib(200, 200, 256);      
    var background = pic.color(23, 0, 0, 50); 

    var my_png = pic.getBase64()

    var overlay = new L.ImageOverlay(  my_png   , bounds, {opacity: 0.5,});
    mymap.addLayer(overlay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a URI problem. You need to add a "data:image" for your image to appear. 
[MDN data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

You can see an example that works on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leafletimageoverlay-6f7do).

```
var pic = new PNGlib(200, 200, 256);      
var background = pic.color(23, 0, 0, 50); 

var my_png = pic.getBase64()
const b64ImgUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${my_png}`;

var overlay = new L.ImageOverlay(  b64ImgUrl   , bounds, {opacity: 0.5,});
mymap.addLayer(overlay);
```